# Sobel Filter implementation for Harris Corner Detector

Tags: computer-vision

I have to implement a Harris detector and am not quite sure about the following detail regarding the Sobel filter to obtain the image derivative. 
When applying the Sobel filter to a Grayscale image, I might get negative intensity values. Do I need to convert the Image back to a Matrix of only positive values before I calculate the Harris Matrix for each pixel or am I supposed to use the values as they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to restrict it to only positive values.

You can look at [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/)'s Harris corner detection implementation (Matlab/C source included). It's in the toolbox directory: vl_harris.m

Comment: Ok but what is the better way to implement the Harris Corner Detector? When I restrict values to positive Values only I find far less Feature Points while if I use negative values as well I find extremly many points, which does not seam right to me either. I calculate R = det(M) - 0.04(trace(M))² and my Understanding was that all R > 0 are classified as Feature Points, however, if I use negative Values I have to increase the threashold up to 10000 or so to achieve usable results.

Comment: No restriction but with non-max suppression. Have you looked at the vl_harris implementation?

Comment: I have and implemented my own filter accordingly, I was just wondering about the difference in the number of points found. But ok i will then focus on NMS, thanks for your help